# Missing arrow on tooltip in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, react-bootstrap

So I'm using react-bootstrap to implement a tooltip to my react application.

When using their tooltip, im not getting any default styling at all to it. So to solve this I had to add some css, however I can only add some css to the body.

An image to show you what I mean. [image]

In my case im missing the arrow. Should the arrow not be there by default?

I've followed the https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/ and have followed the examples they've given me.

```
<OverlayTrigger
  placement="right"
  overlay={
    <Tooltip id="tooltip-right">
      Tooltip on <strong>Right</strong>.
    </Tooltip>
  }
>
  <Button variant="secondary">Tooltip on right</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.tooltip-arrow {
    content: "";
    background: #333;
}
```

UPDATE: Solved by creating my own arrow with css:

```
 .tooltip::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -7px;
    top: 43%;
    content: '';
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #333;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

But it's a temporary solution only, hoping to know why the default arrow isn't displaying.

Comment: Have you add this  `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` somewhere in your css or App.js file?
Your code looks to work fine in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-lake-mpg8e?file=/src/App.js:162-208) without adding style

Comment: antoineso, is it really necessary when you have the bootstrap dependency installed?

tried `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` but got `Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

Comment: Solutions go in the answer space below. Do not edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation we can read that:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise
> version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However,
> some stylesheet is required to use these components.
> [link to the doc part](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets).

you can import those stylesheets either like this:

```
{/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/}

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Or like this:
directly in the index html

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

like explain in the doc:

> How and which Bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the
> simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN. A little
> more information about the benefits of using a CDN can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp).

Comment: Thank you, the reason why I earlier got "Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'" is because I was missing the boostrap dependency.
I only added the react-bootstrap so I had to use `npm install bootstrap` and then `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest reactstrap (9.1.3) and bootstrap 4 I needed to add the following to my bootstrap import to fix the arrows.

```
.bs-tooltip-auto {
  &[data-popper-placement^="top"] {
    @extend .bs-tooltip-top;
  }
  &[data-popper-placement^="right"] {
    @extend .bs-tooltip-right;
  }
  &[data-popper-placement^="bottom"] {
    @extend .bs-tooltip-bottom;
  }
  &[data-popper-placement^="left"] {
    @extend .bs-tooltip-left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Tolltip on show down arrow

```html
<OverlayTrigger overlay={<Tooltip id="tooltip-disabled">Tooltip!</Tooltip>}>
  <span className="d-inline-block">
    <Button style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
      Disabled button
    </Button>
  </span>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

```css
.popover{
    .arrow{
        background:transparent !important;
        z-index: 99;
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-top: 7px solid #c7c7c7;
        bottom: -7px;
    }
}
```